# Android: Activity destroyed, handler lost. How to preserve - e.g. in onSaveInstanceState())?

Tags: android, multithreading, android-activity, orientation, handler

I have an Activity (the main activity) that is displaying progress for an operation running on another thread.  It has a handler member that is called by the thread, and this handler updates progress bar, etc.

If orientation is changed during this process, the activity is destroyed and re-created in the other orientation.  Any suggestions for dealing with this?  It must be a common enough problem, but I don't think I understand the paradigm.  I'm pretty new to android development and this seems to be an issue of fundamentals.  Hopefully someone here can help.

Example.  SomeClass gets a reference to the handler (method SomeClass.setHandler()), and sends message with status information to it.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

private Handler handler;

private createHandler() 
{
   handler = new Handler() {
        @Override
        public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
          // updates views in MainActivity, e.g. ProgressBar and TextView
        }
   }
}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    createHandler();
}

protected void doThingsInSepThread() {
    Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable () {
       @Override
       public void run() {
          SomeClass sc = new SomeClass();
          sc.setHandler(handler);
          sc.method();
       }
    });
}

....
```

};

Comment: BTW, I should have mentioned that I am overriding onSaveInstanceState() to deal with saving the state of certain things already.  Problem is the handler is lost - the thread no longer has a reference to a valid handler for the new activity.

Answer (score 4):

This is a very common problem, because if you change the orientation the Activity will be destroyed and recreated. Because of this your handler is lost as you recognized. You can't save a Handler in onSaveInstanceState(), because it only takes Objects which has the Parcelable/Serializable interface and the Handler has none of these.

One possibility was(is) a method which is deprecated to save an instance of an Object in this situation

```
@Override
public Object onRetainNonConfigurationInstance() {
    if(handler != null)
        return handler;
    else 
        return null;
}
```

In your onCreate you can get that saved instance with

```
Handler savedHandler = (Handler) getLastNonConfigurationInstance();
if(savedHandler != null)
    handler = savedHandler;
```

But because it is deprecated you should use another option to deal with this.

If you wanna stick with your Thread you should consider a `Non-UI Fragment and set retainInstanceState(true)`. With this the Fragment survives the recreation of the Activity and your Thread is save. Here is a good [tutorial](http://www.androiddesignpatterns.com/2013/04/retaining-objects-across-config-changes.html) about this, but it uses an AsyncTask. Just replace it with your Thread and it's good.

Another possibility would be an IntentService. Have a look at this [tutoria](http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android/android-fundamentals-intentservice-basics/)l.

This are the best two options IMO to do threading in Android.

Comment: Thanks, I really appreciate the answer.  I think I will use the fragment approach.